# why can't I write to /var/www/html/index.html from Plotly?

Tags: python, linux, apache, raspberry-pi

I'm logging data from a BME280 sensor with a Raspberry Pi Zero W. I compile the data in a text file and then visualise it with Plotly. I want to write the output to /var/www/html/index.html so that Apache can serve the plot across my network. Here's some very stripped-down code.

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as offline
import numpy as np

N = 1000
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y = np.sin(t)

fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=t, y=y, mode='markers'))

fig.write_html('/var/www/html/index.html')
```

This throws:

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
> '/var/www/html/index.html'

I've followed the instructions in [this guide](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-apache/) to change the permissions and ownership of /var/www/html. I've also tried changing the ownership of the file itself without success. Can someone tell me what I need to do to be able to write to that file from Python?

Comment: Not sure, but try running python script using sudo.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the file got written if I ran the script as root so I've scheduled it in the root crontab and it's working fine.

I'd still like to understand why it would't work after changing all the permissions and ownership of the file.

Comment: If you changed the ownership to root and were running in your user (say "chris") then it won't allow it. You need to be root to run something owned by root. At least that's what I think.

Comment: The directory you were trying to write to (/var/www/html) is not owned by the pi user. It is normally owned by root. Hence you don't (as the pi user) have the ability to write to that directory. Also, the permissions for group and owner are only read (r) by default and so also do not allow writing to that directory

Comment: "I've followed the instructions in this guide to change the permissions and ownership of /var/www/html. I've also tried changing the ownership of the file itself without success."